# Looping over each divs then applying css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to loop over a set of divs with the same class and run some jquery. It's running correctly for the first div but for the next 3 it apply's the same css rather than running again. I've tried a few things but still not getting it to work. Currently my jquery

```
$('div.service-card').each(function() {
   var test = $(this).find('.shbw').outerWidth();
   $('.service-triangle').css('right', test + 'px');
});
```

And the html

```
<div class="service-card">    
    <div class="service-triangle"></div>
    <span class="shbw">Test 1</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">    
    <div class="service-triangle"></div>
    <span class="shbw">Test 2</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">    
    <div class="service-triangle"></div>
    <span class="shbw">Test 3</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">    
    <div class="service-triangle"></div>
    <span class="shbw">Test 5</span>
</div>
```

Any idea how i can apply it to each div individually?

Comment: Instead of `$('.service-triangle').css('right', test + 'px');` use `$(this).find('.service-triangle').css('right', test + 'px');`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla – `service-triangle` is a child, not element itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` to select the the element `.service-triangle` from the current `div.service-card`

```
$('div.service-card').each(function() {
   var test = $(this).find('.shbw').outerWidth();
   $(this).find('.service-triangle').css('right', test + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***[`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)***

Use `this` context inside handler function, A context is nothing but a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context.

```js
$('div.service-card').each(function() {
  var test = $(this).find('.shbw').outerWidth();
  $('.service-triangle', this).css('right', test + 'px');
  //--------------------^^^^^^
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 1</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 2</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 3</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 5</span>
</div>
```

**Without using `jQuery.each`**

```js
$('div.service-card .service-triangle').css('right', function() {
  return $(this).next('.shbw').outerWidth();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 1</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 2</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 3</span>
</div>
<div class="service-card">
  <div class="service-triangle"></div>
  <span class="shbw">Test 5</span>
</div>
```